# Working with Join in C#

Tags: c#, database

I am receiving syntax error on it, getting problem while working with join in C#?
Here is my code.

```
DataTable t1 = new DataTable("Data");

string connectionString = ;

SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

string q = "select s.id,s.username,s.city,s.institute,q.total,q.attempt,q.skipped,q.correct,q.incorrect q.marks,q.percentagecorrectness from student s,quizresult q where s.username=q.studentname";

SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(q,c);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
c.Open();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;            
da.Fill(t1);
```

Comment: And are you going to tell us what the error is? Don't make people who are trying to help you do more work.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near '.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your connection string??

```
string connectionString = ;    // syntax error
```

You're missing a comma between two columns:

```
... q.incorrect q.marks ...    // runtime exception
```

Comment: oh comma was missing...now it is working.Thank a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing **comma** here:

```
q.incorrect q.marks
```

it should be:

```
q.incorrect, q.marks
```

Second  thing there is no connection string provided and its also syntax error:

```
string connectionString = ;
```

this should be:

```
string connectionString = "connection string";
```